# Error Cache Miss ON Pressing Browser Back Button

Tags: jsf, browser-cache

I am making a simple web application using JSF. But, I'm facing a issue Now. 
My application has two pages. 1st page has one form and 2nd page does some processing based upon form values. I'm using view scoped beans in both pages.
I'm using no cache filter so the when user press back button, browser send request to server and not load page from cache. Also I'm using PRG pattern to send data from the 1st page to 2nd page.

**Problem**: When I fill form on 1st page and press submit button , if some validation error occurs, page1 rendered directly as expected. After correcting the error, when I again press the button, I go to Page2. But now if I press browser back button page 2, I get Error Cache Miss Error instead of PAGE 1.

**EDIT**: If I submit the form correctly on 1st attempt and go to page 2 and then press browser back button, I'm getting the page 1 load correctly from server. SO the problem occurs when Page1 is load again on some validation error and then go to page2.

I understood the cause of problem. The cause is that when page 1 is loaded 2nd time due to validation error, this is post request. So the source initiator of page 1  is now post request. When I go to page 2 and press browser back button, browser sends a post request for Page 1 instead of get request and hence Cache Miss error occurs.
In short, browser is checking whether the source of page 1 is get or post request. If no validation error occur on page1, then the source of page 1 is get request and when I press back button on page 2, page 1 is loading fine.

AnyBody know how to convert browser back button request to get from post?

NO cache filter I'm Using:

```
@WebFilter(servletNames = {"Faces Servlet"})
public class NoCacheFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        if (!req.getRequestURI().startsWith(req.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)) { // Skip JSF resources (CSS/JS/Images/etc)
            res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
            res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
            res.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.

            // Clickjacking Protection
            res.addHeader("X-FRAME-OPTIONS", "SAMEORIGIN");
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        // Do Nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // Do Nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use ajax to submit form?

Comment: @BalusC thanks. that solved the problem. But, it is a very common scenario. I think Jsf should have a inbuilt handler for this situatuion